# Produtos Relacionados

Tags: php, pdo

Como eu faço para o produto escolhido não aparecer nos produtos relacionados?

```
$stmtProdRel = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *  FROM produtos as p                                      
                                        WHERE p.produtos_situacao = 1 AND 
                                              p.produtos_categoria = :categoria");   
$stmtProdRel->bindParam(':categoria', $resultProd->produtos_categoria);
$stmtProdRel->execute();   
$resultProdRel = $stmtProdRel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: poderia explicar melhor qual a sua duvida?

Comment: https://atelieflordelis.com.br/produto/acucena-aramada/14 --- Estou fazendo este site... mas quero tirar o produto escolhido acima dos produtos relacionados

Comment: ok, mas esse select que você colocou traz os produtos relacionados?

Comment: Produto escolhido onde ou em que momento?

Comment: @TalesPeres sim. Traz. Eu quero que o produtos nao aparece nos relacionados.

Comment: @Bruno no link que coloquei nos comentarios. Ele aparece como se eu estivesse vendo mais informacoes do produtos. mas quero que ele nao apareça nos relacionados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente, uma das formas de se resolver essa questão é via SQL. Passe o produto selecionado para o trecho de código que você postou e adicione uma condição de exclusão ao SQL.

Por exemplo, se o produto tem um código:

```php
$stmtProdRel = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *  FROM produtos as p
                              WHERE p.produtos_situacao = 1 AND 
                              p.produtos_categoria = :categoria AND
                              p.produtos_codigo <> :codigo");
$stmtProdRel->bindParam(':categoria', $resultProd->produtos_categoria);
$stmtProdRel->bindParam(':codigo', $resultProd->produtos_codigo);
$stmtProdRel->execute();
```